# DynamoDB - Time an hour behind

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dateComposite variable that holds an id with the date saved to dynamo. I'm having an issue when the time is saved as one hour behind (BST). Is there any way to save this as BST to prevent any need for time conversions?

The string is saved as -
2022-04-25T09:24:29.280Z#e01d3989-5a4f-471e-878b-6bcaccd1414b

To display -
25/04/2022 - 09:24

```
<div>{{(row.createdDateComposite).substring(0,10) | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} - </div>

createdDateComposite: string;
```

I'm saving it as a string and using a substring parser to get the correct format, I just need it to be the correct time!

Thanks

Comment: Just add `- hh:mm` to your date pipe?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the DatePipe uses the JavaScript date object internally which is always based off of UTC, so if you're seeing a discrepancy in the hours after adding them to your pipe, then the likely culprit is timezone. You can either change the global injected `DATE_PIPE_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE` or provide another argument to your pipe to fix the locale/timezone.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this previously it just adds the time and I can display it as I need to but the issue is the time is an hour behind what I need it to display.